# How to find duplicates in a list, but ignore the first time it appears?

Tags: python, list

I got a list of 40 words which i took out of a txt file. I've found the duplicates, and replaced them with the same word but then with "*" infront and behind. The code looks like this:

```
def show(self, list1):
    a = [x for x in list1 if list1.count(x) > 1]
    lista2 = ["*"+s+"*" if s in a else s for s in list1]
    print(lista2)
```

Input:

```
> ['utanför', 'dörren', 'stod', 'en', 'man', 'och', 'lyssnade', 'intensivt', 'i', 'den', 'mörka', 'korridoren', 'han', 'hade', 'skuggat', 'digby', 'groat', 'hela', 'eftermiddagen', 'och', 'följt', 'efter', 'honom', 'in', 'i', 'huset', 'när', 'han', 'fick', 'hära', 'ljudet', 'av', 'fotsteg', 'från', 'rummet', 'smög', 'han', 'sig', 'in', 'i']
```

Output:

```
> ['utanför', 'dörren', 'stod', 'en', 'man', '*och*', 'lyssnade', 'intensivt', '*i*', 'den', 'mörka', 'korridoren', '*han*', 'hade', 'skuggat', 'digby', 'groat', 'hela', 'eftermiddagen', '*och*', 'följt', 'efter', 'honom', '*in*', '*i*', 'huset', 'när', '*han*', 'fick', 'hära', 'ljudet', 'av', 'fotsteg', 'från', 'rummet', 'smög', '*han*', 'sig', '*in*', '*i*']
```

Note that the duplicates have a `*` infront and behind.

TL:DR I want the first duplicate to be ignored and the rest to be highlighted with * infront and behind.

Edit:

> ```
> def show(self, list1):
>     new_list, seen = [], set()
>     for x in list1:
>         if x in seen:
>             new_list.append('*{0}*'.format(x))
>         else:
>             new_list.append(x)
>             seen.add(x)
>     print new_list
> ```

appears to work like a charm.
The only thing now that I want to add is to make it case sensitive. As in if "Han" and "han" have occured that it notices that it's a duplicate.

Comment: You misspelled `höra`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def show(self, list1):
    new_list, seen = [], set()
    for x in list1:
        if x in seen:
            new_list.append('*{0}*'.format(x))
        else:
            new_list.append(x)
            seen.add(x)
    print new_list
```

Comment: You could also modify `list1` in place, saving some memory.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer Nooodl! I was also wondering how would i make it case sensative?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `set` to keep a track of seen items:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> new_lis = []
for x in lis:
    if x in seen:     #if item is present in the set `seen` then add the `*`'s
        new_lis.append('*' + x + '*')
    else:    
        seen.add(x)   #item seen for the first time, add it to the set and the list 
        new_lis.append(x)
```

Using a generator function:

```
def solve(lis):
    seen = set()
    for item in lis:
        if item in seen:
            yield '*' + item + '*'
        else:    
            seen.add(item)
            yield item

>>> new_lis = list(solve(your_lis))
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through and replace an element with the asterixed version if it appears in the sliced list.  Keep track of current index with `enumerate`

```
lista2 = [s if s not in lista[:i] else '*'+s+'*' for i,s in enumerate(a)]
```

Comment: While this works, it has quadratic complexity compared to the linear complexity of the other solutions.

Comment: For a list of 40 elements, I feel that a 1-liner is preferable to a new function declaration.  But if you want it to be fast when scaled up then yes this is too primitive.